# Add an array to an ActiveRecord object during api call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two classes called classrooms and students.  They have a many-to-many relationship because classrooms can have many students, but also students can belong to many classrooms.  When I make an api call to get a partular classroom, I would also like to grab all the students belonging to that classroom (through the StudentClassroom join table) and add them to the Classroom ActiveRecord object that I am returing from the api.

If I pause execution with a binding.pry I before returning the response in the controller, @Classroom.students will return an array of student records as expected.  However, when  @Classroom gets sent to the front end it gets stripped of the students array.  What am I doing wrong?

Classroom class

```
class Classroom < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :student_classrooms
    has_many :students, through: :student_classrooms
    def get_classroom_students(classroom_id)
       StudentClassroom.where(classroom_id: classroom_id)
    end
end
```

Controller

```
def show
    students = @Classroom.get_classroom_students(@Classroom.id)
    # somehow add students to @Classroom ActiveRecord object
    render json: @Classroom
  end
```

Comment: Try first converting the classroom to a Hash (e.g. the `attributes` method), and then simply adding students to the hash and rendering that.

Answer (score 0):

This would never return students to the front end. When you add `binding.pry` and test that on the controller you still have the `ActiveRecord` object which has the `students` method defined but when you pass it to the front end you convert it to JSON:

```
render json: @Classroom
```

So that JSON doesn't have the student array. To fix this you could try this on the show action:

```
def show
  render json: @Classroom.as_json(include: students)
end
```

This will include `students` in the JSON you are passing to the front end.

In case you want to make this behavior default, i.e., whenever the `Classroom` object is converted to JSON then include the `students` you can add `as_json` method on `Classroom` class like this:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super({ include: :students }.merge(options))
end
```

Now, whenever the `Classroom` object is converted to JSON it would include the students. Examples:

```
# this will automatically include the students in your controller action
render json: @Classroom

# this will also have the students included
Classroom.last.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `render` no magic happens: before being sent in the response body your classroom object gets *serialized*.

Default json serialization for the AR models is roughly speaking a hash of attributes - no associations, no instance methods etc. You can workaround this behavior via redefining `as_json` for the model as another answer suggests, but this is generally a bad idea - you might (and most probably will) need different serialization for different endpoints and/or scenarios, so having just one hardcoded in the model will force you to add more and more hacking.

The way better idea is to decouple serialization from the business logic - this is where *serializers* come into play. Take a look at https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer for example - this is what you need to solve the task in a clean and maintainable way.

Just define a serializer

```rb
class ClassroomSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer

  attributes <attributes you would like to expose>
  has_many :students
end
```

(just a draft - refer to the documentation to unleash all the power :)) and you're good to go with something as simple as just:

```rb
def show
  render json: ClassroomSerializer.new(@classroom).serializable_hash
end
```